# javascript of firefox and chrome compatibility between windows and mac

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have an javascript application which I created on windows for windows browsers and released on the internet.

I bought an iMac last week.
And I found the application can run normally on mac, too.

I need to maintain and modify the application in the future.
And I want it to run on both windows and mac.

If javascript of firefox and chrome of mac have complete compatibility against those of windows,
I need neither windows machine nor windows in the bootcamp.

Do javascript of firefox and chrome of mac have complete compatibility against those of windows?
Or should I test the application not only on mac but also windows for every update?
I don't want to do that if possible.

Comment: It will definitely run. Whether it will look the same is a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript in Chrome / Firefox / Safari **should** be the same on OSX and Windows provided you are using equivalent versions between OSX and Windows. If you find any differences, then you'd probably be best to file a bug with them.

Mind you, I am talking about just pure JavaScript. If you are worried about how it displays, then it will probably be different. Browsers render certain components differently depending on the operating system; such as the default font, the chrome of the buttons, etc.

You should be more concerned about the version of the browser when testing, not the platform it is running on.

Comment: thank you for your good answer. 
i dont care how it displays.
do you know the reason why JavaScript in Chrome / Firefox / Safari should be the same on OSX and Windows?

Comment: @js_ because that is one purpose of websites - to be portable. People don't want to code for different browsers AND operating systems. So a good browser should try to keep everything the same across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Platform-specific bugs are few and far between, but the are possible. [Yahoo tests](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/) on multiple operating systems, not just multiple browsers. It's a question of how careful you want to be. For most sites, you can probably assume that the OS won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're saying is accurate, then it was a mistake in the design of the JavaScript.  You should have been testing for particular JavaScript capabilities, but it seems in you were testing for browser names.